# Add items to Select2 Cascade

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, select, jquery-select2

my English is not good. sorry.

and I do not know Json and Ajax.

I want add More than two item to [Select2 Cascade](https://codepen.io/ajaxray/full/oBPbQe/).

I created one more select/option(#model) and It does not work.

I created three files in the json folder: animal.json , Vehicles.json , horse.json

animal.json and Vehicles.json files run and executed, but horse.json file is not run and executed.

I want the third select/option(#model) to prop and open, when I select the Horse.

I saw the following page but I do not understand it. Can you modify or create my code here?
http://ajaxray.com/blog/select2-dependent-cascading-select-list-reload/

My Json files is as follows:

```
{
"201" : "Horse",
"202" : "Elephant",
"203" : "Donkey",
"204" : "Camel",
"204" : "Tiger"
}
```

```js
var Select2Cascade = ( function(window, $) {

    function Select2Cascade(parent, child, url, select2Options) {
        var afterActions = [];
        var options = select2Options || {};

        // Register functions to be called after cascading data loading done
        this.then = function(callback) {
            afterActions.push(callback);
            return this;
        };

        parent.select2(select2Options).on("change", function (e) {

            child.prop("disabled", true);

            var _this = this;
            $.getJSON(url.replace(':parentId:', $(this).val()), function(items) {
                var newOptions = '<option value="">-- Select --</option>';
                for(var id in items) {
                    newOptions += '<option value="'+ id +'">'+ items[id] +'</option>';
                }

                child.select2('destroy').html(newOptions).prop("disabled", false)
                    .select2(options);
                
                afterActions.forEach(function (callback) {
                    callback(parent, child, items);
                });
            });
        });
    }

    return Select2Cascade;

})( window, $);

$(document).ready(function() {
    var select2Options = { width: 'resolve' };
    var apiUrl =  'json/:parentId:.json';

    $('select').select2(select2Options);                 

    var cascadLoading = new Select2Cascade($('#type'), $('#subtype'), apiUrl, select2Options);
cascadLoading.then( function(parent, child, items) {
    // Open the child listbox immediately
    child.select2('open');
    // Dump response data
    console.log(items);
});
        var cascadLoading = new Select2Cascade($('#subtype'), $('#model'), apiUrl, select2Options);
cascadLoading.then( function(parent, child, items) {
    // Open the child listbox immediately
    child.select2('open');
    // Dump response data
    console.log(items);
});
     $('#subtype').prop('disabled', true);
     $('#model').prop('disabled', true);

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Select2</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
    
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2-bootstrap-css/1.4.6/select2-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="type" class="col-sm-5 control-label">I'd like to ride</label>   
              <div class="col-sm-5">
                <select name="type" id="type" class="form-control">
                  <option>--Select your ride--</option>
                  <option value="animals">Animal</option>
                  <option value="vehicles">Vehicle</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="subtype" class="col-sm-5 control-label">More specifically</label>       
              <div class="col-sm-5">
                <select name="subtype" id="subtype"  class="form-control">
                    <option>-- Select type first--</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
  <div class="form-group">
              <label for="model" class="col-sm-5 control-label">More specifically</label>       
              <div class="col-sm-5">
                <select name="model" id="model"  class="form-control">
                    <option>-- Select type first--</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>           
          </form>
          </body></html>
```

Comment: what you want to add in third select option ? what will be relation ?

Comment: @aviboy2006 Horse subset. For example, types of race

Comment: added answer but if you give more details about relation of subset or sample json it will easy to solved.

Comment: @aviboy2006 Example, Select1: (Country) = Options: USA, CANADA, BRITAIN, | Select2: (State for USA) = Options: New York, California | Select3: (City for California) = Options: Los Angeles, San Diego

Comment: you can try adding dependancy to this values create. Only issue in your code was using id you are doing. User class keep id unique.

Answer (score 1):

Here is changed code. Based on assumption you need third item. Generally `id` should always unique whenever there is duplication of `id` in code its doesn't work for second one. You have to keep different `id` or modify code using `class`

```js
var Select2Cascade = (function(window, $) {

  function Select2Cascade(parent, child, url, select2Options) {
    var afterActions = [];
    var options = select2Options || {};

    // Register functions to be called after cascading data loading done
    this.then = function(callback) {
      afterActions.push(callback);
      return this;
    };

    parent.select2(select2Options).on("change", function(e) {

      child.prop("disabled", true);

      var _this = this;
      $.getJSON(url.replace(':parentId:', $(this).val()), function(items) {
        var newOptions = '<option value="">-- Select --</option>';
        for (var id in items) {
          newOptions += '<option value="' + id + '">' + items[id] + '</option>';
        }

        child.select2('destroy').html(newOptions).prop("disabled", false)
          .select2(options);

        afterActions.forEach(function(callback) {
          callback(parent, child, items);
        });
      });
    });
  }

  return Select2Cascade;

})(window, $);

$(document).ready(function() {
  var select2Options = {
    width: 'resolve'
  };
  var apiUrl = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ajaxray/32c5a57fafc3f6bc4c430153d66a55f5/raw/260a653e6347fb6d2360e8ec376a2dc4888c1afa/:parentId:.json';

  $('select').select2(select2Options);

  var cascadLoading = new Select2Cascade($('#type'), $('#subtype'), apiUrl, select2Options);
  cascadLoading.then(function(parent, child, items) {
    // Open the child listbox immediately
    child.select2('open');
    // Dump response data
    console.log(items);
  });
  var cascadLoading = new Select2Cascade($('#subtype'), $('#model'), apiUrl, select2Options);
  cascadLoading.then(function(parent, child, items) {
    // Open the child listbox immediately
    child.select2('open');
    // Dump response data
    console.log(items);
  });
  var cascadLoading1 = new Select2Cascade($('#type'), $('#subtype_1'), apiUrl, select2Options);
  cascadLoading1.then(function(parent, child, items) {
    // Dump response data
    //console.log(items);
  });
  $('#subtype').prop('disabled', true);
  $('#subtype_1').prop('disabled', true);
  $('#model').prop('disabled', true);

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Select2</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">

  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2-bootstrap-css/1.4.6/select2-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="type" class="col-sm-5 control-label">I'd like to ride</label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <select name="type" id="type" class="form-control">
          <option>--Select your ride--</option>
          <option value="animals">Animal</option>
          <option value="vehicles">Vehicle</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="subtype" class="col-sm-5 control-label">More specifically</label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <select name="subtype" id="subtype" class="form-control">
          <option>-- Select type first--</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="subtype" class="col-sm-5 control-label">More specifically 2</label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <select name="subtype" id="subtype_1" class="form-control">
          <option>-- Select type first--</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But I want each option to have a subset and click on that option to open its subset

Comment: If u give subset sample and relation it will be helpful

Comment: Example, Select1: (Country) = Options: USA, CANADA, BRITAIN, | Select2: (State for USA) = Options: New York, California | Select3: (City for California) = Options: Los Angeles, San Diego